Passing websocket data to another python program
I have a fairly typical websocket-client program that reads from the wss server.
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

api_data = {
        "type": "subscribe",
        "channel": "v4_orderbook",
        "id": 'BTC-USD',
}

async def wsrun(uri):
        async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri):
                await websocket.send(json.dumps(api_data))
                while True:
                        print(await websocket.recv())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wsrun('wss://indexer.v4testnet.dydx.exchange/v4/ws'))

The above program as it is written above just prints all the data to the screen, but what I need to do is pass the data to another python program asynchronously.  So that means i have to replace the print() statement but I have no idea what to do.
The reason I have to do that is because the second program may need to take time to process the data while the first program (that reads the websocket) can't be delayed at all and must keep running and not lose any messages.  Given a sufficiently large buffer so that the first program can keep pumping data into the buffer without waiting for the second program.

I just want to make sure I understand the question: Is the second program a separate executable or a Python module that can be imported or something else? Also, your last sentence ("Given a sufficiently ...") is not clear since it is not really a complete idea since it is missing the "then" clause. What are you trying to say? If your asyncio generates messages on average faster than the second program can process them, you will eventually run out of storage.

assume i have infinite storage (well I have 512GB).  Also it's a separate python program.  For example, the program example above is called 'server.py'.  I will then run a 'client.py' that will receive the output from server.

I just don't know what client.py will look like.  The server code will change the print(await websocket.recv()) line to something like sendtoclient(await websocket.recv()) but what does the client.py look like?

I am working on the assumption that it might be advantageous, depending on what client.py needs to do to process a message, to have multiple processes processing these messages in parallel. If that is not the case, then in server.py you can set the n_processes variable to 1.
client.py
We create a function process_message that processes a single message:
"""client.py"""

def process_message(message):
    """Do something with message."""

    ...

server.py
We create a multiprocessing pool with N processes (N might be 1 as previously described) that can process N messages in parallel to improve performance. Then for each input message we submit a new task to the processing pool:
"""server.py"""
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

from client import process_message

api_data = {
    "type": "subscribe",
    "channel": "v4_orderbook",
    "id": 'BTC-USD',
}

async def wsrun(uri, pool):
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri):
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(api_data))
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            # Submit a new task to the multiprocessing pool:
            pool.apply_async(process_message, args=(message,))

def main():
    # Create a process pool:
    n_processes = cpu_count() - 1  # Leave a core for us
    pool = Pool(n_processes)

    while True:
        try:
            uri = some_uri
            asyncio.run(wsrun(uri, pool))
        except Exception as error:
            pass  # Ignore exception (or log it)
        else:
            # If wsrun ever returns, then wait for all submitted
            # tasks (i.e. messages to process) to complete:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Required by Windows, for example
    main()

Update Using asyncio.loop.run_in_executor
server.py
"""server.py"""
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
from os import cpu_count
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

from client import process_message

api_data = {
    "type": "subscribe",
    "channel": "v4_orderbook",
    "id": 'BTC-USD',
}

async def wsrun(uri, pool):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    async for websocket in websockets.connect(uri):
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(api_data))
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            # Submit a new task to the multiprocessing pool:
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, process_message, message)

def main():
    # Create a process pool:
    n_processes = cpu_count() - 1  # Leave a core for us
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(n_processes)

    while True:
        try:
            uri = some_uri
            asyncio.run(wsrun(uri, pool))
        except Exception as error:
            pass  # Ignore exception (or log it)
        else:
            # If wsrun ever returns, then wait for all submitted
            # tasks (i.e. messages to process) to complete:
            pool.shutdown()
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Required by Windows, for example
    main()


Your solution was perfect.  In the last 3 hours, I also managed to write something that worked using multiprocessing.process() and multiprocessing.pipe().  Now I am not sure which solution is better, do you have an opinion on that, @booboo?  see the code at https://imgur.com/a/bTXawDV

Do not use Pipe! Your main sever process will block writing to a Pipe if the client is delayed from reading from it. A Queue instance is built on top of a Pipe but uses a separate thread that processes put requests by storing the messages as they are put and then sends it through the Pipe. If the client is not doing timely get requests then the Queue’s thread will block but the main thread doing the puts will not block.

If there is a problem reading from websocket connection, then wsrun() returns an exception and then I do pool.close() and pool.join() but measuring how long this takes, I found it takes over 12 minutes.  Is there any way to make it take less time before I restart the wsrun() ?  this screenshot show the server.py main() code https://imgur.com/a/rxXmsYY  I don't need to save any old work/data that may be sitting in the Pool(), because when I restart the websocket it will download all the data again

The sequence pool.close(); pool.join() waits for all submitted tasks to complete and it seems like there is a lot of them. You could instead issue pool.terminate() and then any tasks that have been submitted but not yet started or completed will immediately be purged. But why not just put the pool = Pool(n_processes) statement before the while True: statement and replace the calls to pool.close() and pool.join() with a pass statement? I have updated the code to demonstrate this.

File "/home/vmware/extra/server.py", line 40
catch Exception as error:
^^^^^
SyntaxError: expected 'except' or 'finally' block

I changed "catch Exception..." to "except Exception".  Thanks!

is it correct to say that 'else:' block would never execute because errors would go to the Exception block?

Your suggestion was perfect!  The 12-minute delay is completely gone

The else block is only executed if the try block completes normally, that is to say that the call to asyncio.run(wsrun(uri, pool)) returns without raising an exception. In this case you do want to wait for any outstanding tasks to complete before terminating. As your code is currently posted, wsrun never returns so the else block will not be executed.

The solution works but I think maybe there is a memory leak or something like that because the amount of RAM consumed keeps going up higher and higher.  Do you think that is the case?

I really couldn't say for sure. But if your server is getting messages faster than the client can process them, as I have already indicated in my comment to your post then the pool's task queue will continue to grow indefinitely. I suspect that to be your problem.

I guess you are right here is a chart of free memory over time which shows a gradual linear drop over time https://imgur.com/a/akYSf6s   I am only using n_process = 1 for the pool because I want the messages to be read from websocket and processed sequentially

Is it possible to start multiple 'client.py' in parallel because the server.py is reading much faster than the client.py can keep up  https://imgur.com/a/rzRMz17

The code already can execute n_processes calls to process_message in parallel using a multiprocessing pool. I have also added an update that uses asyncio.loop.run_in_executor, but since you are not going to issue an await against the returned awaitable, it shouldn't matter which version of the server you use. If you cannot process messages fast enough, you may want to look into using a message queue library that supports distributed programming, such as Celery or RabbitMQ.

Of course, if you set n_processes to 1 you are not executing the client in parallel. So you need to use a value other than 1 and deal with message processing order. Do you really need the messages to be processed in order or is just that you need the results to be obtained in submission order? If the latter, pass a message number to the client starting with 1, 2, 3, ... etc. and write the results to a database table using the message number as a key. Then you can read from the database sorted by message number.

If you explained (preferably in another post) what the client is doing, where it is running (a different computer), what its constraints are exactly, etc. somebody may be able to offer up a solution.

The client is saving the data in a PostgreSQL database, 1) inserting new rows when 'price' is new, and 2) deleting when 'size' = 0 and there is existing record for that 'price', and also 3) checking the max-width of both 'price' and 'size' and storing that in the database (these variables get used for display-gui).  That's it, but the server is so much faster than database operations.  Thanks for the suggestion about n_processes I will increase it to 4 and test again.

The reason to want message processing in order is: if we try to delete a record before the insert .  For example, if message 'n' is insert and 'n+2' is delete that record, but due to parallel operations, 'n+2' got processed before 'n'

server+client runs on the same server.  Each instance of server+client is for 1 market, so I have 35 (or more) of these running at the same time, but one constant problem is that one or more of these server+client instances would be 'stuck' on the first websocket message (messageid = 1) and I don't know why. see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/6MotCjp

I know for a fact when it is stuck, the server.py is stuck on this line message = await websocket.recv() so if there is a way to make this line automatically error out if nothing is received after 'x' seconds, that would be ideal, otherwise it is stuck forever

Changing n_process to 2 or higher will not work, it appears there are database issues when I change this.  The error seems to be when the client.py is checking to see if that price record already exists in the database, when n_process = 2, it throws the error Future exception was never retrieved future: <Future finished exception=ProgrammingError("the last operation didn't produce a result")> therefore I must keep n_process=1 https://imgur.com/a/c2va3Tr

If I run many server+client instances (due to many different markets and I need one instance for each market), approximately 3-4% of the instances get stuck on await websocket.recv()  I wasn't able to figure out why so I ended up switching the server.py to use Tornado websocket client example from https://github.com/ilkerkesen/tornado-websocket-client-example and this client doesn't have that problem
